# How to add `OR` operator to validation rule?

Tags: laravel, validation, digits

I am using validation in Laravel 5.7. I would like to use digits 10 numbers or 16 numbers for id_number in validation. How could I handle it? any suggestions?

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'id_number' => 'required|digits:10 or digits:16',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `In` validate rule for it.

```
return [
        'params.personal_information.id_number' => 'required|in:10,16',
    ];
```

Or with `Rule::in` you may use like this.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'params.personal_information.id_number' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in([10, 16]),
    ],
]);
```

Please check the document for [more info](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-in)

**Edit:-**

As your comment, you wanted that the id_number should be between 10 to 16 so you may use `between` rule.

```
'params.personal_information.id_number' => 'required|between:10,16',
```

Comment: thanks for your response. actually, I mean 10 or 16 numbers (characters) not only 10 or 16 number.

Comment: do you mean digits between 10 to 16(10,11,12,13,14,15,16) ?

Comment: No, I mean id_numbers could be 10 digits (example. 1234567890) or 16 digits (example. 1234567891234567). sorry, I cant explain my question clear.

Comment: Here is one method `digits_between`  but it'll check 10 to 16 method. Or you can do one thing for this you can make your custom validator as digits limit 10 or 16 should be accepted.

Comment: Got your solution? If yes let me know how did you do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own rule by adding a new [rule object](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#using-rule-objects) or adding a [rule extension](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#using-extensions).

Otherwise the [regex-rule](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-regex) might work in your case:

```
'foo' => 'regex:/^(\d{10}|\d{16})$/i'
```

(*Code above ins not tested*)

Comment: thank you.. This code is wrong but I found I should use regex.. thanks